# Accessing particular instance of variable from for loop ( scope issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Pretty new to any kind of programming, so sorry if this is a mess!
I have a chloropleth map where the colors are determined by a slider, and that's working fine. BUT, I need to display the value that gets used to determine the color in a text field when each specific shape on the map is clicked - and have that still update when the slider is used.

I can get it to calc properly for the area inside the click, but then it doesn't update with slide, so i think i need it outside the click, and then just some show/hide on click. But outside of the click, I have no "this" to reference and can't get at the iteration I need.  I've been trying every possible thing I come across, and am now totally lost.

Couldn't thank you enough for any help/explanation.

What I've got is:

```
function fromslide(){




// Set properties for each county.
for (var i=0; i < counties.length; i++) {
ctys = counties[i];
//console.log (ctys);
var id = ctys.data("id");
alloc= ((parseInt(Landvar[id].val) * landweight) + (parseInt(Popvar[id].val) * popweight)  + (parseInt(Poorvar[id].val) * poorweight));
console.log(alloc);




// Set county color.
ctys.attr({
fill: getColor(alloc/ 1000000),
});


//console.log (selectedcnty);
console.log (window.selectedcnty);



//this is what's not working
if (selectedcnty = String(id)) { thisalloc = ((parseInt(Landvar[id].val) * landweight) + (parseInt(Popvar[id].val) * popweight)  + (parseInt(Poorvar[id].val) * poorweight));}
$("#allocfield").val(thisalloc);        







ctys.click(function() {


for (var i=0; i < counties.length; i++) {
var ctys = counties[i];
var id = ctys.data("id");
ctys.attr({stroke: "#fff" });
};
this.toFront();
this.attr({stroke: "orange" });
var name = this.data("id"); 
$("#namefield").val( Popvar[name].name);    
$("#popfield").val( Popvar[name].val);
$("#landfield").val( Landvar[name].val);
$("#poorfield").val( Poorvar[name].val);


console.log(thisalloc);

window.selectedcnty = name;  

console.log (window.selectedcnty);
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? What variable/data are you trying to access outside of the click?

Comment: yes! sorry if I wan't clear. alloc sets the colors for each area on the map based on the slider values. I want to display that for an individual county on click, but still have the # update as the slider is used.  So, I was trying to get the name of the county globally from within the click with window.selectedcnty=name, and use it to match with the ID to create "thisalloc" (to go in the text field).  Don't know if that route necessary.  alloc in console logs for each shape, I just can't get at the chosen one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working adding

```
window.selectLand = parseInt(Landvar[name].val); 
window.selectPop = parseInt(Popvar[name].val); 
window.selectPoor = parseInt(Poorvar[name].val);
```

to the click funct, then using that for "thisalloc" above it.  It does what I need, but it seems like an inelegant way to go about it.Seems there must be a way to reference the instance of "alloc" that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable outside of any functions, and then you can access it from within the function calls. You're right about `this` - it's not a variable, but a special keyword that references the object instance that "owns" the method that's being executed. In order to pass data from one function to another across function calls, you'll need to store it in a global variable. Just declare the variable outside of any function, and reference it from within the function *without* using `this`:

```
var myVar = 0;
function myFunc() {
    myVar++;
    alert(myVar);
}
```